# wp_dropdown_categories - remove &nbsp;

Tags: dropdown, categories

I need to remove the auto adding of `&nbsp;` in the `wp_dropdown_categories`, it causes a problem in the jQuery multi select dropdown plugin I'm using.

Example value:

```
<option class="level-1" value="120">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Apples&nbsp;&nbsp;(125)</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `echo` parameter to return the output into a variable:

```
$html =  wp_dropdown_categories( array( 'echo' => 0 ) );
```

and then replace `&nbsp;`:

```
echo str_replace( '&nbsp;', '', $html );
```

Comment: Thanx, How do I add "<select multiple="multiple">" to the form select elements?

Comment: You could do similar replace: `$html =  str_replace('<select', '<select multiple="multiple"', $html );`